# Get element name with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have JSON like this:

```
{"foos":[{"id":1}, {"id":2}]}
```

I can turn it into `List<Foo>` pretty simply with GSON, like this:

```
Type t = new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType();
JsonObject resp = new Gson().fromJson(
    new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject().get("foos",t);
```

But let's assume that I also have another JSON, where the name of the array and type changes

```
{"bars":[{"id":3},{"id":9}]}
```

Of course I could just swap the "foos" parameter for "bars", but if it's possible, I'd like my software to do it for me.

Is there a way to extract the name of the array child with the GSON library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want correctly, but aren't you referring to the use of generics? I mean you could write a method that returns you a List of your relevant class? Something along the lines of

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>() {}.getType();
List<MyClass> myObjects = getMyObjects(new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject().get("foos"), type);

public static List<T> getMyObjects(String jsonString, Type type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<T> myList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);

    return myList;
}
```

Comment: I can, but I'd like to extract the key name first

Comment: When you say "key", the only thing that comes to mind is a HashMap. You use a string key such as "foo" or "bar" and retrieve the list of objects against it, something like Map<String, List<MyClass>> myObjectMap = new HashMap<String,List<MyClass>>. And after that you could use myObjectMap.get("foo") and retrieve the list of MyClass objects against it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your JSON examples, I assume that the name of the list element can change, **but not the content of the list**. If this is correct, you could parse your JSON response just like this:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Foo>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, List<Foo>> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, mapType);
```

And then you can access the name of the list with:

```
String listName = map.keySet().iterator().next();
```

If the content of the list could also change, things get a bit more complicated...

Comment: The type of the items in the list might change (a bad example), but maybe this approach will work too, if I use a TypeToken for Map<String,Object> (or sufficiently generic second type parameter)